How to fix negative rear camber?
Negative camber on both rear wheels. Severely wearing the insides of tires prematurely.
However I've been told on this forum and elsewhere that for most cars today, alignment adjustment is not performed for rear wheels. So what about camber?
Alternatively, I also thought about swapping out the rear struts with new ones, but they are not leaking and they pass the "bounce" test so now I'm thinking it might not be that either.
So how can I adjust the camber?
And if it's not that, what else could it be? Control arms, tie rods, ball joints, etc. And how to tell WHICH it is?
Should I aim to replace ALL rear suspension components?
Scion tC 2005, 145,000 miles.

For some reason a lot of manufacturers don't allow for rear camber adjustment. It may be an initial cost savings but has become a headache for owners of older cars. The rear suspension parts can all be in serviceable condition but not able to be brought in to alignment.  The aftermarket has realized the potential for sales for certain popular models. A search for "Scion adjustable rear camber retrofit kit" will yield a variety of sources. It can be done at home in your drive way or a shop can do it. Either method will require a wheel alignment to be done after installation. You must also replace any other worn out rear suspension parts while doing the upgrade.

Thanks, great info. I probably should have  also mentioned I bought it used, and the guy before me had it lowered.  Could that have something to do with it?

If the rear was lowered by altering or replacing the rear springs the above mentioned kit may or may not provide enough adjustment. It may be that the kit is designed  because lowering that particular vehicle is popular. The alignment shop should be able to tell you how many degrees of adjustment you need. The kit manufacturer should be able to tell you how many degrees the kit can add.
